# R Summary based on column name length

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

I have the following problem:
I have a matrix with 80 columns which names have either 10/11, 21/22,31/32 or 42/43 characters. The names are totally different but the lenth fits always in one of the four groups. Now I would like to add four columns were I get the sum of all the values of columns corresponding to one group. Here is a little example of what I mean

```
a<-rnorm(1:100)
b<-rnorm(1:100)
cc<-rnorm(1:100)
dd<-rnorm(1:100)
eee<-rnorm(1:100)
fff<-rnorm(1:100)
g<-data.frame(a,b,cc,dd,eee,fff)
g$group1<-"sum of all columns of with headers of length 1 (in this case a+b)"
g$group2<-"sum of all columns of with headers of length 2 (in this case cc+dd)"
g$group3<-"sum of all columns of with headers of length 3 (in this case eee+fff)"
```

I was able to transfer the matrix to a dataframe using melt() and carrying out the operation  using stringr::str_length(). However, I could not transform this back to a matrix which I really need as final output. The columns are not in order and ordering would not help me much, since the number of columns depends on the outcome of the previous calculation and it would be too tedious to define dataframe ranges every time again.
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
tmp <- nchar(names(g))
chargroups <- split(1:dim(g)[2], tmp)
# `chargroups` is a list of groups of columns with same number of letters in name
sapply(chargroups, function(x) {
    if(length(x)>1) # rowSums can only accept 2+-dimensional object
        rowSums(g[,x])
    else
        g[,x]
})
# `x` is, for each number of letters, a vector of column indices of `g`
```

The key part of this is that `nchar` is going to determine how long the column names are. The rest is pretty straightforward.

EDIT: In your actual code, though you should deal with the ranges of name lengths by just doing something like the following after you define `tmp` but before the `sapply` statement:

```
tmp[tmp==10] <- 11
tmp[tmp==21] <- 22
tmp[tmp==31] <- 32
tmp[tmp==32] <- 43
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas that does the job. What would I need to change if I would like to have the values for every row individually and this even attached to the dataframe g?

Comment: Take a look at `rowSums` instead of `sum`. That would return a vector of row sums for each grouping of columns, which you could then easily `cbind` to the original df.

Comment: works for the example provides. If I add another column with length=4 (e.g. "hhhh") it gives me the following error: "Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions"  How to account for this? I was not able to do it with the help provided in the manual. What does the "x" in your command stand for and where is it generated? Sorry if that questions seems stupid but I do not totally understand why your code works. However, for the example that I provided  it does.

Comment: @user2386786 Check out the edit. `rowSums` doesn't accept a vector as its input, only a 2+-dimensional array, so the code now will give you the row sum if more than one column is the group or just the value of the column if there is only one column.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
set.seed(123)
a <- rnorm(1:100)
b <- rnorm(1:100)
cc <- rnorm(1:100)
dd <- rnorm(1:100)
eee <- rnorm(1:100)
fff <- rnorm(1:100)
g <- data.frame(a,b,cc,dd,eee,fff)

for ( i in 1:3 )
    eval(parse(text = sprintf("g$group%s <- rowSums(g[nchar(names(g)) == %s])", i, i)))

## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  9 variables:
##  $ a     : num  -0.5605 -0.2302 1.5587 0.0705 0.1293 ...
##  $ b     : num  -0.71 0.257 -0.247 -0.348 -0.952 ...
##  $ cc    : num  2.199 1.312 -0.265 0.543 -0.414 ...
##  $ dd    : num  -0.715 -0.753 -0.939 -1.053 -0.437 ...
##  $ eee   : num  -0.0736 -1.1687 -0.6347 -0.0288 0.6707 ...
##  $ fff   : num  -0.602 -0.994 1.027 0.751 -1.509 ...
##  $ group1: num  -1.2709 0.0267 1.312 -0.277 -0.8223 ...
##  $ group2: num  1.484 0.56 -1.204 -0.509 -0.851 ...
##  $ group3: num  -0.675 -2.162 0.392 0.722 -0.838 ...
```